# Android Xhdpi Screen Settings for eclipse editr

Tags: android, editor, screen-resolution

what are the emulator and visual editor settings(screen resolution) in eclipse that should be used for a screen density of xhdpi(320).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these resolutions:

2048x1536
2560x1536 
2560x1600

Check the table on this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of Emulator settings for

- LDPI
- MDPI
- HDPI
- XHDPI

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/emulator-settings-for-each-android-density/